# NSClickGestureRecognizer - how to pass on the click once recognised

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, mouseevent, gestures

In my `ViewController` I have set up a `NSGestureRecognizer` in order to know when  particular TextField is clicked in by the user.

in `viewDidLoad()` override  I have

```
let gesture = NSGestureRecognizer()
gesture.buttonMask = 0x1
gesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
gesture.target = self
gesture.action = #selector(ViewController.textOutputClicked)
textOutput.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

then later in my ViewController I have

```
@objc func textOutputClicked(sender: NSGestureRecognizer){
    print("textOutput was clicked")
}
```

This all works and when I click in the textOutput field, I get the message "textOutput was clicked", however the processing of the click stops. What I want to do, and I'm not sure of the right way to describe it, is to continue passing the click onto the control to process. So for example the insert point is set in the control - right now this is ignored

Thanks
GS

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
  @objc func textOutputClicked(sender: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
// Invoke the default click behavior
NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSResponder.mouseDown), to: nil, from: sender)}
```